# arrays not recognized outside of for loop

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to write a program that takes input from an external file, prints it, then calculates total world length and also the frequency of 3 letter words within the file. I'm only supposed to use string methods... I have tried to create an array of lines from the input and then create another array using .split to analyze each word. However, everytime I try to test wordcount or write a code segment to calculate frequency of 3 letter words, I get an error of can not find symbol... I don't know what this means. Can someone help me with what the error means and how to fix it, please?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Program
{
public static void main(String args[]) 
{

Scanner inFile = null; //adds the data
try { 
inFile = new Scanner (new File("prog512h.dat"));} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
System.out.println ("File not found!");
System.exit (0);}      

    String[] line = new String[18]; //there are 18 lines of code in the external file
    int wordcount=0;


    for (int i=0; i<18; i++){
    line[i] = inFile.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line[i]);
    String word[] = line[i].split(" ");  
    }

    wordcount = word.length();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Total Wordcount: " +wordcount);

}}
```

The external data file referenced reads this:

```
Good morning life and all
Things glad and beautiful
My pockets nothing hold
But he that owns the gold
The sun is my great friend
His spending has no end
Hail to the morning sky
Which bright clouds measure high
Hail to you birds whose throats
Would number leaves by notes
Hail to you shady bowers
And you green fields of flowers
Hail to you women fair
That make a show so rare
In cloth as white as milk
Be it calico or silk
Good morning life and all
Things glad and beautiful
```

Comment: scope, scope and scope. You need to define the array outside of the loop and probably rethink about your assignation in the for loop to ensure the value is not written over

Comment: I tried that already, but when I define array outside of loop, I can't use word[] without defining length...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a local variable inside a loop, so as soon as you leave the loop it goes out of scope.

Read up on variable scoping for more detail. The easiest fix is to declare the variable before you enter the loop - although note that that would overwrite the variable each time so only the last time around the loop would do anything.

You probably actually want to do:

```
wordCount += word.length;
```

**Inside** the loop.

Comment: I get this error when I try that: Program.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
        wordcount += word.length();
                         ^
  symbol:   method length()
  location: variable word of type String[]
1 error

Comment: Sorry, its an array not a string so it should be .length; without the brackets. I'll fix it.

Comment: Okay, that worked thank you! Now, how do I test length of an individual word in the array within that loop? Is there an easier loop?

Comment: word[index].length() would give you the length of the string at position index in the array. The real question is what you plan to do with the information?

Comment: Use an if then statement to determine whether the length of the word was equal to 3 and set a counter probably... but the wall I keep running into is how do I test every index... after the whole for loop runs, all without leaving the scope of the array.. see the issue?

Comment: It sounds like you need a nested loop scanning the contents of word[] inside your outer loop.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, your code as it is, doesn't make very much sense.  Even if `word[]` was visible outside your for loop, it would only represent the very last line after the loop was done.

But, if you just want to update the wordcount without making any major changes to your code, you can update `wordcount` inside your loop

```
int wordcount = 0;

for (int i=0; i<18; i++)
{
    line[i] = inFile.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line[i]);
    String word[] = line[i].split(" ");  
    wordcount += word.length;
}
```